# SQL Server 2008 Backup Transaction Logs

Tags: sql-server, logging, transactions, database-backups

I understand that the transaction logs keep a record of historical transactions in order to facilitate a restore if needed. However do I need to keep creating transaction log backups for inactive databases that are hanging around on the server? No DDL statements are run against them and they are just used for reference.

I am just a bit worried that I might run out of log space if I get this wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered changing the recovery model of your databases to the [SIMPLE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) recovery model? Doing so would negate the need to backup the transaction log as it would be automatically re-used in the "unlikely" event that you need it to be.

I would still advise that regular FULL database backups be taken.

Also, if these database are indeed true read only databases then why not consider [setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) them to be so. This action would have the advantage of immediately highlighting any queries/users that are "still" issuing DML operations when you believe there to be none.

Other options for identifying queries that are performing more than just READ operations include running a Profiler Trace of activity on your database server and also an aggressive option would be to revoke all data modification rights from the relevant database Users.

Comment: Looks like your updated answer includes what I said below as your original response only touched on the SIMPLE recovery model. Good thing we're suggesting the same I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Transaction logs are actually truncated when they're backed up. So, if these databases are actually inactive, you shouldn't be backing up any transaction logs for them since the logs would be empty.

Also, common practice for "inactive" databases would be to make them READ ONLY with a SIMPLE recovery model.

Comment: Cheers for the response Bitxwise, was very useful.